# using grep command to search man pape

Tags: linux

Although the man page have so many information, I need a little bit of it at once. For example, objdump -f kernel.o, but I forgot the feature of the flag '-f'.

I try this but fail.

```
man objdump | grep -e '*.(\-)f.*'
```

The error message as following:

```
<standard input>:161: warning [p 1, 5.5i]: can't break line
<standard input>:594: warning [p 6, 6.5i, div `an-div', 0.0i]: can't break line
```

How do I search the man page using grep?

Comment: `man` pages have these errors sometimes; often you don't notice because stderr is lost by your pager before you see it. (WIBNI there was an error summary on stdout at the end!)

Comment: Searching in your pager is probably a lot more effective. In `less` (and I guess `more`) slash `/` is regex search; try `/^ *-f` or maybe `/^[ \ ]*-f` where the second whitespace is a tab.

Comment: Also, [Google is your friend](http://google.com/search?q=man+objdump).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ man objdump | grep -e "-f"
<standard input>:161: warning [p 1, 5.5i]: can't break line
<standard input>:590: warning [p 6, 6.5i, div `an-div', 0.0i]: can't break line
               [-f|--file-headers]
               [-F|--file-offsets]
               [--file-start-context]
               [-s|--full-contents]
       -a,-d,-D,-e,-f,-g,-G,-h,-H,-p,-P,-r,-R,-s,-S,-t,-T,-V,-x must be given.
       -f
       --file-headers
       --file-offsets
       --file-start-context
       --full-contents
           all of -a -f -h -p -r -t.
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: But, why does it output warning message?

Comment: Not really sure. even using escape characters causes the same errors.